# TYPO3 - Different models for different actions in ExtBase

Tags: typo3, extbase

I would like to adress different models for different actions in the same controller and the same type of objects.

For example, in List view I need some additional previews of thumbs, and in Detail view I need more fields. In JSON view I need some additional properties.

So, could we organize Models on per action basis, keeping same data tables behind ?

Comment: That sounds pretty unorthodox to me. Why can't you just put everything into the model and represent parts of that everything in each action? Apart from that, I'd like to have a db table independent data structure, like in a flexform, so you don't have to make changes to the db if you introduce a new field. But that isn't your issue, is it?

Comment: There is too much magic there :) too many relationship between fields, TCA and dB. In my case the solution could be : in the Action get only records IDs and to add properties 1 by 1, instead of initiation of all related data. Need to check, if it's possible. About Your case : I suppose, if You have no definitions of additional fields in the TCA, You could add additional properties freely to Your model and to get it in FE, without to modify the database.